# How can I effectively propagate parameter uncertainties from one hierarchical level to the next in Bayesian hierarchical modeling?

Tags: python-3.x, bayesian, pymc3, mcmc, hierarchical-bayesian

I am using PyMC, the probabilistic programming library of Python to implement a hierarchical bayesian model.

Consider a two-level Bayesian hierarchical model. Level-1 has a parameter m1 and level-2 has parameters m1 and n1. I want to infer m1 in the first level, and then use the entire inferred distribution of this parameter in the second level to infer just n1.

I **do not** want to use just the posterior mean of m1 after level-1 of inference, since that would be quite deterministic. Additionally, it will not propagate the uncertainty of parameter m1 into the second level. **So my question is:** What would be the recommended approach to do this in pymc?

So far from my limited understanding of pymc, what I can think of are:

1. Shared variables
2. Data containers

But both these seem to be intended for different purposes. Any comments on the issue or a recommendation of a better approach would be very helpful. Thanks to all the very nice people here.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow"). For us to help you, provide the expected [mre]. We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points. This allows testing suggestions against your data and desired output.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I had previously posted my question with the main error I get with a reproducible example in here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77661219/how-to-resolve-input-dimension-mis-match-error-in-hierarchical-bayesian-inferenc

Comment: But since it did not get any replies and since I had a feeling that the question was too complex to ask in one go, I was trying to solve the issue by breaking it down to bits. If you could have a look, it would be very helpful @itprorh66

Comment: I think your question in that is asking for a recommendation related to an approach is too broad. Questions that ask for general guidance regarding a problem approach are typically are not a good fit for this site.  Split your task into smaller ones and start working on them. And ask particular questions related to particular issues you encounter. Here'